# python for each in list: item is not defined

Tags: python, urllib2

I have list that is iterated over in for loop:

```
list = [a, b, c]

for each in list:
     print each
```

I receive the error:

```
name 'a' is not defined
```

Comment: I answered your question first. Don't you think you have accepted other users answer.

Comment: Thanks!. Appreciated.

Comment: Not sure what happened. I did initially accept you because you were first. I changed it back. Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error you are getting is correct. You need to initialize your list like below.

Change `list = [a, b, c]` to `list = ['a', 'b', 'c']`

You need to have list of values instead of variables. Compiler is looking for variable "a" which is not defined hence throwing that error.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting that error because you have a `list` of `variables` not `values`.

`list = [a, b, c]` is looking for the variables `a`, `b`, `c`.

You need to add `'` or `"` around each `list` iterable to make them `values`.

Such as: `list = ['a', 'b', 'c']` or `list = ["a", "b", "c"]`.

The choice of `'` vs `"` will depend on what characters lay between the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Change your first line i.e. list declaration to

```
list = ["a", "b", "c"]
```

It will work. Rest everything is okay.